# Sending JSON params with HTTP Post in Objective-C (iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c

I wrote this function to make a post / get call to my web server with iOS, and what happens is that the request is sent without the JSON params (and therefor the server errors and says required parameters are not there).

**Edit:**
Took some of the advice got in the comments and removed the encode/decode of data. Same problem.

Also attaching the call I made to the function:

```
NSArray *keys=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"token", nil];
NSArray *objects=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:token, nil];
NSLog(@"Log: %@", [self makeServerCall:@"user/login" keys:keys objects:objects isPost:YES]);
```

Here's the code:

```
+ (NSString*)makeServerCall:(NSString*)urlSuffix
                           keys:(NSArray*)keys
                        objects:(NSArray*)objects
                         isPost:(BOOL)isPost{
    NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys];

    NSError *error;
    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:params
                                                       options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted
                                                         error:&error];

    if (!jsonData) {
        // should not happen
        NSLog(@"Got an error parsing the parameters: %@", error);

        return nil;
    } else {
        NSString *jsonRequest = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", urlPrefix, urlSuffix]];

        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                                           cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:20.0];

        // choosing method according to boolean 
        NSString* method;
        if (isPost) {
            method = @"POST";
        }
        else {
            method = @"GET";
        }
        [request setHTTPMethod:method];
        [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
        [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [request setHTTPBody: jsonData];

        NSURLResponse * response = nil;
        NSError * error = nil;
        NSData * data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                              returningResponse:&response
                                                          error:&error];

        // TODO: error handling
        NSLog(@"Response: %@", response);
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        NSLog(@"Data: %@", data);

        NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        return returnString;
    }
}
```

Comment: At a first glance, this looks okay. Have you validated the JSON you're using? Why are you converting your jsonData NSData object to an NSString and then back to NSData? There doesn't seem to be a need to convert it to a string, but I don't see that it would cause your problem either, unless there's a weird encoding issue.

Comment: Have you run through single-step with the debugger to confirm things are being set up how you think they are?

Comment: Also, while your code looks OK for the POST method, it won't work for the GET method because you aren't putting any parameters into the URL and the body will be ignored on a GET

Comment: What am I suppose to be looking for? When I take a look at jsonData or requestData during debugging I can't see much in there, just NSObjects.

Comment: @LiorZ To Paulw11's point, this won't work for `GET`. What is your `isPost` value? (As an aside, the setting of the `Content-length` is not necessary, as `NSURLConnection` will set that header for you. Also, your converting the `jsonData` to a `NSString` and back to a `NSData` is unnecessary, too.)

Comment: Assuming you're doing a `POST`, have you tried looking at the request in [Charles](http://charlesproxy.com) (or equivalent tool)? Are you confident that the web service is correct and that it's not, for example, looking for `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` request? Looking at the request in Charles will help differentiate between request problems and server problems. It's a great way to diagnose your client code.

Comment: Hi, made changes you guys offered (edited the post as well). The web service works great with other clients. The return error specifics that the value cannot be found in the parameters, so that's the problem. I'll try to get Charles to use, but can anyone come up with a solution from what I've written?

Comment: OK. Looked in it with a packet sniffer, and the JSON appears as { "token": "XXXXXXXX" }. Now, in another client that works, the JSON appears in the packet as token=%22XXXXXXX… XXX%22. Does anyone know how do I get this type of encoding?